# Spring4D: resolve a TFrame with owner in create

Tags: delphi, spring4d

I have some Frames registrated like:

```
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TfraBasePage, TfraSetting>(IDSettingPage);
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TfraBasePage, TfraCurrency>(IDCurrencyPage);
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TfraBasePage, TfraTicketLayOut>(IDTicketLayOutPage);
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TfraBasePage, TfraSetUp>(IDSetUpPage);
```

I can call the frame like:

```
  Result := GlobalContainer.Resolve<TfraBasePage>(aPageName);
```

But the constructor 'create' the owner is nil.
How can I pass an owner component?

Now I solve this with 'InsertComponent' after the resolve.

```
var
  oFrame: TfraBasePage;
begin
 oFrame:= GlobalContainer.Resolve<TfraBasePage>('SettingPage'); 
  if assigned(oFrame) then
  begin
    Self.InsertComponent(oFrame);
  end;
```

Is this also possible with a Factory?

```
 TfraBasePage = class(TfraBase, IPage)
...

 TfraSetting = class(TfraBasePage)
...

 IPageFactory = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{2E40E3C4-87B7-4313-BE0A-29202B7EB5A1}']
    function Create(aOwner: TComponent): TfraBasePage;
  end;
...

GlobalContainer.RegisterFactory<IPageFactory>;
GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TfraBasePage, TfraSetting>('SettingPage');

...
var
  oFrame: TfraBasePage;
begin
 //Here I can't solve how to get the 'SettingPage' Frame with the factory.
 //I miss something, the ('SettingPage') is on the wrong place.
 oFrame:= GlobalContainer.Resolve<IPageFactory>('SettingPage').Create(Self);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

```
uses
  Classes,
  Spring.Container;

type
  TBaseFrame = class(TComponent) // just for testing a TComponent descendant
  end;

  TDemoFrame = class(TBaseFrame)
  end;

  TFrameFactory = reference to function(const serviceName: string; owner: TComponent): TBaseFrame;

procedure Main;
var
  owner: TComponent;
  frame: TBaseFrame;
  factory: TFrameFactory;
begin
  GlobalContainer.RegisterType<TBaseFrame, TDemoFrame>('myframe');
  GlobalContainer.Build;

  owner := TComponent.Create(nil);
  owner.Name := 'owner';

  // Possibility 1 - pass args to Resolve -
  // they will be matched via their type when looking for an appropriate ctor
  frame := GlobalContainer.Resolve<TBaseFrame>('myframe', [owner]);
  Writeln(frame.Owner.Name);

  // Possibility 2 - register a custom factory function -
  // RegisterFactory does not support passing the serviceName through the factory interface
  GlobalContainer.RegisterInstance<TFrameFactory>(
    function(const serviceName: string; owner: TComponent): TBaseFrame
    begin
      Result := GlobalContainer.Resolve<TBaseFrame>(serviceName, [owner]);
    end);
  GlobalContainer.Build;

  // don't forget the parentheses here else the compiler will barf 
  // because return type is something invokable
  factory := GlobalContainer.Resolve<TFrameFactory>(); 

  frame := factory('myframe', owner);
  Writeln(frame.Owner.Name);

  // yes, memoryleaks - demo code to answer the question
end;

begin
  Main;
  readln;
end.
```

Comment: Nice, I use the first possibility. I didn't know that I can pass args. I've learn something today. Thanks

Comment: I suggest looking into utilizing the second option by injecting the factory into whoever needs to create those frames - because that is doing real DI. Furthermore in the future the container internally might be optimized to not look for a matching ctor every time but only once. But this optimization is only possible when not passing custom arguments to the Resolve call which affects which ctor is suitable.

Comment: ok, I set the second option. Must I aad a guid to the TFrameFactory?

Comment: I get an error on second option. error: class ERegistrationException with message 'Type is missing a guid: Project2.TFrameFactory'.

Comment: If you are using 1.2 - then apply this commit to fix this issue: https://bitbucket.org/sglienke/spring4d/commits/0ac3047d7b68eb6592d1acfdb08cfdef34f37d3c